# Cvxpylayers throws an exception: "Problem must be DPP"

Tags: optimization, cvxpy

I have the following optimization layer that I use as output layer in my Pytorch model:

class OptimizerLayer(torch.nn.Module):
"""
Optimizer layer.
"""

```
def __init__(self, n):
    """

    :param n: number of outputs of the model
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.n = n  # dimensionality of the problem
    self.build_layer()

    self.layer = None

def build_layer(self):
    w = cp.Variable(self.n)
    w_model = cp.Parameter(self.n)
    cov_matrix = cp.Parameter((self.n, self.n), PSD=True)

    objective = cp.Minimize((w_model @ w) - cp.sum_squares(cov_matrix @ w))
    constraints = [cp.sum(w) == 1, w >= 0, w <= .3]
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

    self.layer = CvxpyLayer(problem, parameters=[w_model, cov_matrix], variables=[w])

def forward(self, w_model, cov_matrix):
    w_optimal, = self.layer(w_model, cov_matrix, solver_args={"acceleration_lookback": 0})
    return w_optimal
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
    self.layer = CvxpyLayer(problem, parameters=[w_model, cov_matrix], variables=[w])
  File "/Users/p.u/Documents/pf-alloc/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvxpylayers/torch/cvxpylayer.py", line 79, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Problem must be DPP.')
ValueError: Problem must be DPP.
```

Comment: You are trying to minimize minus sum of squares, equivalently maximize sum of squares, equivalently maximize norm. That is not convex and one of the most impossible things in this world. Maybe your cp.Minimize should have been cp.Maximize.

Comment: There are no impossible things. If I say that 1=2, then it is True.